# how to increase the width of two image view in a main view whose sizes are different and get variation in width when changing their orientation

Tags: ios, autolayout, nib

How do I increase the `width` of two `image views` which are located inside a main view  to `landscape`orientation through  a `UIInterface` nib file from portrait orientation, where the sizes of image view are different to one another?

I need a **increase in width** proportional to their default size.

Explain by setting a `constraint` in the nib file.

example, my image view1 is in left corner of the main view and image view2 is in right corner of the main view.both of same height but width is different.first it is in portrait i am setting this in nib file.while running by changing the portrait view into landscape either any one of the sizes gets increased.but my requirement is need to expand the width of both image view from their original width size in correct ratio.for this how to set the constraint in nib file

the image for my requirement 
as in portrait orientation,
[image]

and i need in landscape orientation as,
[image]

here one more doubt was that  cant  make correct streching size  too in horizontal orientation for that orange and white (height i am mentioning here) colour image views.

Comment: You will have to say more. Describe the desired layout. Please edit your question to give more detail. Provide a screenshot of your desired layout in portrait and landscape, if possible.

Comment: yes @Maarten is right. please elaborate more.

Comment: dude as i am beginner i cant able to post my required screen shot ..i will tell u further upto my best...thanks for yur response .. @Maarten

Comment: http://snag.gy/ use this to share your screenshot

Comment: @DhiyanesKaeYes Sorry, dude, but your English is not so great, so a picture would be much easier to understand. Just make a mockup of your app in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Use autosizing functionality.
For more info try this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2